# IntelliJ IDEA autocomplete lowercase SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, intellij-idea

I want to write my SQL code in lowercase and be able to autocomplete. As of now the autocomplete uses uppercase.

Can I solve this?

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 15 autocomplete sql]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it as I'm a stickler for good code practice and using uppercase.

HOWEVER;

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open Settings.

Go to: `Editor > Code Style > SQL` and change `Keywords` to `To lower`

Hopefully it will change function names to lower-case too.
If it doesn't I suspect IntelliJ will auto-complete from the dependency you're using and force you to use upper-case naming conventions. At which point, you're only option is to edit the entire dependency to lower-case.

Comment: I feel like uppercase deters readability as it is easier to read lowercase because that is what you mostly read text as. Thanks for the solution!

I found the "Do not change" option more suitable.

Comment: All 3 major SQL Databases ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), [MS SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.90).aspx) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)) all use uppercase Keywords in their documentation. It also provides a clear difference between table/row/column names and the keywords. I'm pretty sure good practice is to use _uppercase_.

Comment: Woops, forgotten to mention [Oracle 12c](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) as well. Documentation uses _uppercase_.