# Case Sensitive Lower Table and Column

Tags: phpstorm, jaybird

Is it possible to return table and column names with case sensitive lower?

```
<case-sensitivity plain-identifiers="upper" quoted-identifiers="exact"/>
```

Comment: Please provide some more context to your question, it is unclear what you are asking about. Identifiers in Firebird are by default case insensitive, but are case sensitive **if they are quoted**.

Comment: I am using the jaybird together as the phpstorm for connection, during the assembly of the sql in phpstorm when completing the names of the tables and columns it suggests in uppercase, I would like it to be in lowercase, when I checked the connection plan I saw the parameter "case-sensitivity"

Comment: The thing is, in Firebird unquoted names are handled case-insensitive, but they are stored uppercase in the database metadata. PHP storm probably just suggests by reading directly from the metadata, so it gets those names in uppercase. I don't know if PHP storm/IntelliJ has an option to render in lowercase for this situation.

Comment: Ok I managed to solve this using the link below, thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023208/intellij-idea-autocomplete-lowercase-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA autocomplete lowercase SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023208/intellij-idea-autocomplete-lowercase-sql)